# Liquibase column data types mess

Tags: database, numeric, liquibase, bigint

I have an existing database in production. I have exported the schema with liquibase and created a base script to be used when installing for a new customer.
Liquibase exported all my id columns in mssql as BIGINT, but in reality they were NUMERIC in the database.

Now When I am adding an upgrade script that creates a new table and a foreight key to an old table, I am receiving an error: Column is not the same data type as referencing column in foreign key.

What happens is that customer that will only upgrade (and wont have a clean install) will have NUMERIC column in database and it will clash with the new BIGINT column.

The question is what should I do, because for each database type it is also different types. I am lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job of the schema export is to get a starting point for a changeLog. The next version of liquibase is focused on improving the export support, but even with that there will be differences between what the database you are exporting has a type and what you "mean"--especially in a cross-datbase sense.

The normal usage is to call generateChangeLog, then read through what is created and modify it as needed to fix up data types etc. based on your understanding of the database. From that point on, you do the normal liquibase flow of manually appending to your changeLog as you need database changes and then running the modified changelog against the database.